# How to add onclick event inside a json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my json data. I am using this json for creating an tree view, Now  I am not sure how add Onclick Event inside this data that when  i do check or uncheck a checkbox it calls the function where i can track the correspondent id of the chekbox .

```
[{
"id":1,
"text":"Forest",
"children":[{
    "id":22,
    "text":"Animal",
    "state":"closed",
    "children":[{
        "id":31,
        "text":"Lion",
        "checked":true
    },{
        "id" : 14,
        "text":"Tiger"
    }]
  }]
}]
```

The HTML part look likes this:

```
<ul checkbox="true" url="tree_data.json" class="easyui-tree tree" id="tt">
 <li>
 <div class="tree-node" id="_easyui_tree_1">
  <span class="tree-hit tree-expanded"></span>
  <span class="tree-icon tree-folder tree-folder-open"></span>
  <span onclick="check(this.id)" class="tree-checkbox tree-checkbox2"></span>
  <span class="tree-title">Forest</span>
</div>
<ul style="display: block;">
 <li><div class="tree-node" id="_easyui_tree_2">
 <span class="tree-indent"></span>
 <span class="tree-hit tree-expanded"></span>
 <span class="tree-icon tree-folder  tree-folder-open"></span>
 <span onclick="check(this.id)" class="tree-checkbox tree-checkbox2"></span>
 <span class="tree-title">Animal</span>
</div>
<ul style="display: block;">
<li><div class="tree-node" id="_easyui_tree_3">
<span class="tree-indent"></span>
<span class="tree-indent"></span>
<span class="tree-indent"></span>
<span class="tree-icon tree-file "></span>
<span onclick="check(this.id)" class="tree-checkbox tree-checkbox1"></span>
<span class="tree-title">Lion</span>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<div class="tree-node" id="_easyui_tree_4">
<span class="tree-indent"></span>
<span class="tree-indent"></span>
<span class="tree-indent"></span>
<span class="tree-icon tree-file "></span>
<span onclick="check(this.id)" class="tree-checkbox tree-checkbox0"></span>
<span class="tree-title">Tiger</span>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `onclick="check(this.id)"` Here span has no `ID`

Comment: Why you want to add event inside json data. You should write event in html only and use json data to pass the proper parameter to the event function for further use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you implement a dispatch table in your language of choice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715457/how-do-you-implement-a-dispatch-table-in-your-language-of-choice)